# Are derived functors of sheaf-hom out of structure sheaf computing cohomology sheaves of complexes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories

$\newcommand{\OX}{\mathcal{O}_X}\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathcal{H}\text{om}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal}\newcommand{\OXM}{\OX\text{-mod}}$
Are the following three things true?

1. $\hom_{\OXM}(\OX,\C{F})\cong F(X)$ so that $\hom(\OX,-)=\Gamma(X,-)$ are naturally equivalent functors. (Quite confident of this, since the commuting diagrams encoding the $\OX$-module structure ensure that the image of any section $\OX(U)\to \C{F}(U)$ is determined by where one sends $1_X\in \OX(X)$, i.e. $s_U\in \OX(U)$ maps to $s_U\cdot \text{res}^X_U\varphi_X(1_X)$).
2. $\Hom(\OX,\C{F})\cong \C{F}$ i.e. that
   $\Hom(\OX,-)$ is naturally equivalent to the identity functor
   $\text{id}:\OXM\to \OXM$. (This should follow immediately from 1, noting that $\OX|_U = \C{O}_U$ 'local global sections')
3. Being that $\Hom(\OX,-)$ is the identity functor, it is exact, so although it is weird to take left or right derived functors,it certainly is still well defined. But am I correct that $\Bbb{R}\Hom(\OX,-)(\C{F}^\bullet) = \C{H}^i(\C{F}^\bullet)[-i]$ for $\C{F}^\bullet \in D(\OXM)$? Similarly, surely if we take the identity morphism of schemes $\text{id}:X\to X$ then $\text{id}_*:\OXM\to\OXM$ is the identity pushforward, and $R^i \text{id}_*=\C{H}^i(-)[-i]$?

Related questions: assuming 2 is true, is it normal for the internal hom out of the monoidal unit to be the identity functor? So the derived functor associated to $\hom_{\OXM}(\OX,-)$ gives the abelian group 'global section' cohomology, i.e. we take K-injective resolutions and then apply global sections, and then take cohomology as $\OX(X)$-modules. Vs derived functor of $\Hom_{\OXM}(\OX,-)$ gives cohomology sheaves in each degree. Probably this is wrong since I've never seen anyone write that down.

Comment: 1. and 2. are true by the arguments you note. As for 3., I may be misunderstanding because I don't know the derived category perspective, but the usual derived functor of the identity (or any exact) functor is trivial in higher degrees.

Comment: @Thorgott I believe the following is true: When one defines for, say, a left exact covariant functor $F:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ from a grothendieck abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ to some abelian category $\mathcal{B}$, then one takes $R^iF(X)=h^i(F I)$ where $I$ is an injective resolution of $X$. Of course $I$ is an exact complex, but $FI$ need not be. As you remark, when $F$ is exact, $FI$ will be exact, so all higher derived functors will vanish (for any X). But when one looks at $RF:D(\mathcal{A})\to D(\mathcal{B})$, cont...

Comment: Now $RF(X^\bullet)$ is computed by taking a K-injective resolution $I^\bullet$ of $X^\bullet$ (which is quasi-isomorphic to $X^\bullet$, so isn't exact whenever $X^\bullet$ is not trivial in $D(\mathcal{A})$) and $RF(X^\bullet) = FI^\bullet$. Maybe I am abusing notation at the end, but I think $R^iF(X^\bullet) = H^i_{\mathcal{B}} RF(X^\bullet)$, so when $F$ is the identity functor, this should just be $H^iFI^\bullet$ but since $I^\bullet$ is quasi-isomorphic to $X^\bullet$, this should just be $H^iX^\bullet$ (cohomology giving an object of $\mathcal{B}$)

Comment: Very slight mistake in the first comment, I meant to say $I$ and $FI$ are exact above degree $0$, probably anyone would read over that and mentally fix it automatically. (or the complex with augmentation map from $X$ is exact, etc)